# Show that the convolution $u\ast\psi$ between compactly supported tempered distribution $u$ and Schwartz function $\psi$ is a test function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schwartz-space, microlocal-analysis

I am trying to show that $u\ast\psi=v$ for some $v\in\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}$ in the following way:

Step 1: Show that one can define $\langle u\ast\psi,\phi\rangle$ for $\phi\in\mathcal{S}'$

Step 2: Define a candidate for $v$ by using $\delta$-distributions for $\phi$.

Step 3: Show that $u\ast\psi=v$ by taking any $\phi\in\mathcal{S}$ and applying both sides to $\chi_{\epsilon}\ast\phi$ and letting $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.

This question is the exercise 2.2 (4) on the 11th page of Hintz's notes on microlocal analysis, which can be found at [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hintzp/notes/micro.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ehintzp/notes/micro.pdf)

Can anyone please suggest how to solve the question by following the above steps, which are hints of the exercise? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where did you get stuck in following the steps?

Comment: I got stuck at the first step. The only way that I can think of to show the first step is to show that $u\ast\psi$ is smooth, is it the correct way?